# Как стилизовать select и в нем скролл?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот такая у меня форма в макете http://joxi.ru/J2b5xvLs91Rgm6 нашел плагин для select, а вот как внутри него сделать красивый скролл, не знаю, буду благодарен за любые ссылки или информацию.

Comment: Кастомизировать скролл можно двумя способами: стилями (работает только для `webkit`-браузеров, т.е. Сафари, Хром и Опера) или одним из многочисленных плагинов. Для стилизации ccs-ом можно воспользоваться онлайн-сервисом - так проще, если делаете это впервые: https://mikethedj4.github.io/Webkit-Scrollbar-Generator/

Answer (score 1):

Вот [хороший](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html) плагин для кастомных скроллбаров. Инициализируется очень просто:

```js
   
  $(window).on("load",function(){
      $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
  });
```

```css
 .content {
    float: left;
    width: 340px;
    height: 300px;
    background:#e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<script src="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<div class="content mCustomScrollbar _mCS_3">
test test test test test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test test
</div>
```